# supervisor does not write more log

Tags: logging, go, supervisord

I am using supervisord to deploy my go application, and I have a /var/log/supervisor directory, which is the directory of application log. However, I found after certain times. No new log is write to the application log. Seems supervisord cannot write to the file. What can be the reason causing it?

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple reasons for supervisor not being able to write the log files.

1. Maybe you already created the log file with different permissions that don't allow supervisor to write in there.
2. When you don't specify `stdout_logfile` and `stderr_logfile` in your application's configuration, supervisor will append a unique ID at the end of the log file name.
3. Supervisor only writes what's being sent to `stdout` and `stderr`. Are you sure you're not writing somewhere else ?

Also make sure to have a look inside the `/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log` file, maybe there are errors you're unaware of.

Also make sure you read the documentation about child process logging [there](http://supervisord.org/logging.html).

Comment: Is that possible that logrotate setting will interfere with supervisord? I am doubting logrotate is interfering

Comment: I don't think it's possible that it would prevent supervisor from writing logs.